# MS Access button with on click and on double click events (VBA)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a button on a form in ms-access where I have both a "On Click" and "on Dbl Click" events filled.  I am running into the problem that the single click event works but the double click will not unless on the second click, I keep holding it down and drag the mouse off the button before I release it.  What this button does is it fills a textbox with certain text depending on the 2 different clicks. How is it I can fix this double click issue?  The code for the buttons is below.  Note that Task_ID_AfterUpdate() also fills in text fields according to what the Me.Task_ID is by looking it up in a Query.

```
'single click
Private Sub getBtn_Click()
    btnUpdateHelper (1162)
End Sub
```

---

```
'double click
Private Sub getBtn_DblClick(cancel As Integer)
    btnUpdateHelper (1449)
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub btnUpdateHelper(Task As Variant)
    'helper method for buttons, only pass task id
    'Me.Task_ID is a textfield
    Me.Task_ID = Task
    Task_ID_AfterUpdate
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Task_ID_AfterUpdate()
    Dim taskIdNum As String
    taskIdNum = Me.Task_ID
    'updates all fields to display the selected task
    Me.Area = DLookup("Area", "Query", "TaskID=" & taskIdNum)
    Me.Activity = DLookup("Activity", "Query", "TaskID=" & taskIdNum)
    Me.Description = DLookup("Description", "Query", "TaskID=" & taskIdNum)
    Me.Comments = DLookup("Comments", "Query", "TaskID=" & taskIdNum)
    Me.Task_Group = DLookup("[Task Group]", "Query", "TaskID=" & taskIdNum)
    Me.Mul = DLookup("Mul", "Query", "TaskID=" & taskIdNum)
    Me.Time = DLookup("Time", "Query", "TaskID=" & taskIdNum)
End Sub
```

Comment: That is a very strange UI design. May I suggest to use either right-click or Shift+click for the alternate function? Use the `_MouseDown` event to catch these.

Comment: @Andre Thank You!! If you submit that as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `Click` and `DblClick` events on a button is IMO a rather confusing UI design. Better is to use either right-click or Shift+click (or Alt or Ctrl) for alternate functions.

The `Click` event doesn't catch these modifiers, only `MouseDown` and `MouseUp`. It feels most natural if the actions are put in the `MouseUp` event procedure, e.g.

```vb
Private Sub cmdMultiClick_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    Dim SelectedFunction As String

    If Button = acLeftButton Then
        If (Shift And acShiftMask) Then
            SelectedFunction = "Shift-Left click!"
        Else
            SelectedFunction = "Left click!"
        End If
    ElseIf Button = acRightButton Then
        SelectedFunction = "Right click!"
        ' Cancel the default right-click behavior (open context menu)
        DoCmd.CancelEvent
    End If

    MsgBox SelectedFunction, vbInformation

End Sub
```